# How to create feature vector for neural network(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I'm trying to use neural network(multilayered NN) to help me to classify input image into its respective class(3 classes).

I have done as below:

(1)read input image(image)..

(2)apply canny edge detector(image=>edgeimage).

(3)label region in edge `image(length(B)=20,no.of region=20)`

(4)compute feature.

As for computing the image features, for example, in each region, i have computed circularity and convexity which result in 20 feature value for circularity and 20 feature value for convexity. The number of region labeled can also be varied from image to image.

In my current understanding now, the number of input neuron should be in equal to the number of features used. So..number of input neuron is equal to 2(for each circularity and convexity) or it should be 40(for each feature value)..?

And I want to know too, how to create the right feature vector-input and target for my problem.

thanks.

Comment: What does each region represent exactly? Can't you get a constant number of regions from all the images? For example, dividing the image in 4x4 grid and calculating circularity and convexity in each region.

Comment: Regions are obtained and labelled using bwboundaries() which mean each region represent connected pixels. Before that, some regions from canny detector are being removed using bwareaopen(image,p). the p value are being determine interactively, in which that i would observe what p value will give best edge image that can capture the image object while minimizing other edges that represent the background.  And, for calculating the features, i'm using regionprops() and need to get labelled region to use these...

Comment: i'm very new with matlab, so am not used with all the available functions in it. Correct me if i'm wrong and please help me in understanding and solving my problem. thanks.